# Google Maps not displaying inside tab

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps

I have a group of tabs, one of the tabs contains a google map - this is delivered using a shortcode in WordPress (Maps Marker Pro), the issue is when I click on the tab which contains the shortcode which delivers the Google Map, the Map container is present without the map's content.

I know this has something do to with the the Google Map not resizing and having a width of zero, I think? Therefore I tried this...

In the CSS the tabs were originally hidden using display: none; I changed that to and had the tab contents `position; absolute;` and `left: 9999em;`, and when the tab was clicked, the CSS became `left: 0em;`, `position: relative;`.

This didn't work. So I found some jQuery.

```
if($(this).attr('href')=='#ert_pane1-2'){
var center = map.getCenter();
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
map.setCenter(center); }
```

This was supposed to trigger the map to resize when the tab link was clicked, but this didn't work.

This is the tab href, which was in a `<li>` tag with the other tabs

```
<a href="#ert_pane1-2" data-toggle="tab">Map &amp; Directions</a>
```

I have place the above jQuery, and other jQuery functions which I have found on the internet in the header, but I have had no luck.

Considering this Google Map is served through a plugin and shortcode, is there any reason why jQuery could not be working.

The page in question is [here](http://www.bunk.co.nz/accommodation/hostel/oaklands-lodge/), any insights or help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

**Code From Comment:**

```
    '<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
 var center = map.getCenter(); 
if($(this).attr('href')=='#ert_pane1-2')
{ 
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize"); 
map.setCenter(center); } 
}
 </script>'
```

Comment: where is the code snippet you posted located in your script? Is it inside a click - handler, and if yes, does the handler catch the event as intended?

Comment: Hi @GNi33, the code is located in the head of the document. `<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var center = map.getCenter();
    if($(this).attr('href')=='#ert_pane1-2'){
    
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    map.setCenter(center);

    }
}  
</script>`
This is the snippet, I do not think it's inside a click handler.

Comment: jQuery does not track the `href` attribute on the go — instead, you need to listen to an event, such as a click event triggered on the tab, or the load event when the tab's content has been loaded, in order to trigger Google Map to load.

Comment: Thanks @Terry, so you suggest I should surround the function inside a click handler? Like so:-

`$( '#ert_pane1_2').click(function() {
  var center = map.getCenter(); 
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize"); 
  map.setCenter(center);
});`

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @ru-pearls yes, that is one way to do this. Make sure that you have this at the bottom of your page or inside the `$(document).ready` - handler though

Comment: @GNi33, thank you, I did make sure it jQuery was invoked, but unfortunately, the map is still not displaying.

Comment: @ru-pearls I did read over your snippet a little too fast apparently. For `$( '#ert_pane1_2').click` to work, your link would need the id "ert_pane1_2". Either add this or try `$('a[href="#ert_pane1_2"]').click`

Comment: @GNi33 - I have tried `$(document).ready(function(){var center = map.getCenter();
$( 'a[href="#ert_pane1-2').click(function() {  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize"); map.setCenter(center); });
}`

and

`$(document).ready(function(){
$( 'a[href="#ert_pane1-2').click(function() { var center = map.getCenter(); google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize"); map.setCenter(center); });
}`

still no luck getting the map to resize - the second snippet, is with the variable outside the function. This didn't help either.

Comment: @ru-pearls can you provide a full working example? It's hard to pin-point the actual reason of the problem with the details given

Comment: @GNi33. No problem. Here is the page. http://www.bunk.co.nz/accommodation/hostel/oaklands-lodge/